Difference in size and items counting calculations in file manager (rsynced data) in different Ubuntu versions
I am facing a strange issue. I have to exact the same data on two different Ubuntu installations (one legacy 18.04) and one latest 24.04 (vanilla installations).
When I go to the file manager (properties) in order to see the total amount of files and size, I see a different number. The file systems are both ext4. Do you have any idea or clue what is going on?
When I am checking with rsync (dry run), rsync says that both folders are totally synced.
I noticed that in the older Ubuntu version when the hidden files are shown (enabled) then the file size and count is the same as the newer Ubuntu version. This indicates that probably Ubuntu file manager is now counting by default the hidden files? Even the "Show hidden files" are off? Or is something else?


I noticed that in the older Ubuntu version when the hidden files are shown (enabled) then the file size and count is the same as the newer Ubuntu version.

You probably have your answer right there, since this is too much of a coincidence to "just happen". And it's easy to test to.
If you try and enable "Show hidden files" on the 24.04 system, does the file size change? If it doesn't change, then you have reproduced that the 24.04 always includes hidden files (which I would assume to be the case).
